# arduino web client random freeze

Tags: c++, arduino, webclient

I have implemented a web client for arduino to sent data from my sensors to a database throw a GET Http request. The loop randomly freezes on **DEBUG 4**

This is the part of the code and [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15854314/ver4.ino) is the full sketch link.

Any suggestions?

```
sprintf(pageAdd,"/write3.php?value0=%d&value1=%d&value2=%f&value3=%lu&value4=%f&value5=%f&value6=%f&value7=%f&value8=%f", value0, dht_humidity, temperature, pressure, altitude, gust, dir, rain, knots);

if(!getPage(server,serverPort,pageAdd)) Serial.print(F("Fail "));
else Serial.print(F("Pass "));



byte getPage(IPAddress ipBuf,int thisPort, char *page)
{
  int inChar;
  char outBuf[128];

  Serial.print(F("connecting..."));

  if(client.connect(ipBuf,thisPort))
  {

     Serial.println(F("connected"));
    sprintf(outBuf,"GET %s HTTP/1.1",page);
    Serial.println(F("DEBUG 1"));
    client.println(outBuf);
    Serial.println(F("DEBUG 2"));
    sprintf(outBuf,"Host: %s",serverName);
    Serial.println(F("DEBUG 3"));
    client.println(outBuf);
    Serial.println(F("DEBUG 4"));
    client.println(F("Connection: close\r\n"));

  } 
  else
  {
    Serial.println(F("failed"));
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: How much ram are you using in your sketch and how much is available?  I have had issues with unexpected behavior in the past when I ran out of ram without knowing it.

Comment: lol 96% used i will try to close some stuff

Comment: Sending an http request every 5.5seconds right now. 90 completed succesfully. Lets see

Answer (score 0):

sprintf is dangerous.  It will get you by for a quick hack, but if that hack changes you can be in for hard to debug trouble. Instead if you a writing into  a local buffer use snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),.....  It's better to truncate the output than to corrupt memory.

This could be your problem: because pageAdd isn't a very big buffer.

sprintf(pageAdd,"/write3.php?value0=%d&value1=%d&value2=%f&value3=%lu&value4=%f&value5=%f&value6=%f&value7=%f&value8=%f", value0, dht_humidity, temperature, pressure, altitude, gust, dir, rain, knots);

Comment: also tried that way:  


`code`
client.print("GET /write3.php?value0="); 
    client.print(value0); 
    client.print("&value1=");
    client.print(dht_humidity);
`code`

Comment: Any other suggestions guys? Still have the problem !